# Use desktop as camera on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, camera, screen-capture

Hopefully this is not too difficult;

I have an Elgato Game Capture HD, which I am using to capture an HDMI signal. What I want to do is take either the onscreen capture window or the USB signal into the computer and use it as a camera on OS X Mountain Lion in ProPresenter 5.

I downloaded Desktop Presenter, but I do not know where the signal from the program is going to, nor do I know if this will even act as a camera.

Any suggestions? It needs to be recognized the same way the FaceTime Camera is recognized (as a camera).

Comment: I do know another called CamTwist, which is free. But it offers up to 720p, and I am not sure of its quality. It is Mountain Lion-compatible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a virtual webcam software, such as [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/):

> [image: screenshot]
>   Draw over your video window or screencast your desktop online with our software for your webcam